# Is there a fast way delete rows from a table with lots of triggers?

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete, database-trigger

I'm trying to delete rows from a table that has lots of triggers on it.

The database is available to clients so I can't just turn them off, but I could turn it off if it's just for my statement.

I need a way to delete as fast as possible without my clients to notice or meaningful data been lost.

Ideally I want something like:

```
DELETE FROM mySchem.myTable WHERE id = 99 DO NOT FIRE TRIGGERS;
```

Comment: Did you verify that the triggers are **really** the problem? Please **[edit]** your question and add the the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** not jus a simple `explain` - but be aware that that will indeed delete the rows, so you might want to turn off autocommit. Tthat will show us where exactly the time is spent. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I already test turn off the triggers using  'SET session_replication_role = replica;' but i'm not sure if this is safe for my database, do you know if it will interfere with my clients?

Comment: Setting `session_replication_role` in a session is safe and a good solution, as it will not affect other sessions. You might add this as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: post it, you helped

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
SET session_replication_role = replica;
  DELETE FROM mySchem.myTable WHERE id = 99;
SET session_replication_role = DEFALT;
```

This seems to work